# How to execute while loop and for loop conditions in Java?

Tags: java, database, selenium

I have a scenario where there are 5 employee ids. I want to check these IDs status (Status also I am getting from data base). The status of employees are:

`Completed`, `Waiting`, `Error`.

First, the employee id will move from `Waiting` to `Complete` in a certain amount of time. Once all the employee ids are moved to `Complete` status, I have to execute another query (until all employee ids move to `completed` status, I cannot execute the next query).

If any employee ids move to Error state, I have to just display their employee ids. This is what I have tried:

```
public void ValidateStatusQuery() throws Exception {
    int counter = 0;
    List<Integer> EmplyeeIDList= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(123,345,456,567))
    Class.forName(dbdriver);    
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL2,DB_UserName,DB_Password);
    log.info("Data base connection is established");
    int i=0;
    while(i++<EmplyeeIDList.size()) {
        if(counter==5)
            break;
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from tb_Employee where EmployeeID=?");                    
        stmt.setInt(1,EmplyeeIDList.get(i));            
        rs3= stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs3.next()) {             
            getCurrentStatus= rs3.getString("CurrentStatus");
            if(getCurrentStatusID.equals("1")) {
                log.info(+EmplyeeIDList.get(i) + " is in Completed Status");
                counter++;//Incrementing counter variable whenever employee id is in Completed Queue.
                System.out.println("Count is"+counter);
            } else if(getCurrentStatusID.equals("7")) {
                log.info(+EmplyeeIDList.get(i) + " is in Waiting Status");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } else if(getCurrentStatusID.equals("3")) {
                log.info(+EmplyeeIDList.get(i) + " is in Error Status");
            }
        }   //End of While rs loop      
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
123 is in Waiting status
345 is in Waiting status
456 is in Waiting status
567 is in Waiting status
```

It's coming out of the while loop once the `EmplyeeIDList.size()` is completed.

The expected output is: I want to wait till all the caseids move to `Completed` Status.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a partial answer here.  If you just want to find out how many employees are in the completed status, you should use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tb_Employee
WHERE CurrentStatus = '1';
```

Here is Java code to do this:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tb_Employee WHERE CurrentStatus = '1'";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);          
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if (rs3.next()) {             
    System.out.println("Number of completed employees: " + rs.getInt("cnt"));
}
```

You could also run a similar query to find the count of employees *not* in completed status, or in some other status.  This query could be called as part of a scheduled task or thread.

**Edit:** Here is one way to limit the scope of the query to only a certain list of employees.

```
// given EmplyeeIDList
StringBuilder whereIn = new StringBuilder("(?");
for (int i=1; i < EmplyeeIDList.size(); ++i) {
    whereIn.append(", ?");
}
whereIn.append(")");
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tb_Employee ";
sql += "WHERE CurrentStatus = '1' AND EmployeeID IN " + whereIn;
for (int i=1; i <= EmplyeeIDList.size(); ++i) {
    stmt.setInt(i, EmplyeeIDList.get(i-1); ++i);
}
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);          
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if (rs3.next()) {             
    System.out.println("Number of completed employees: " + rs.getInt("cnt"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But  there are many employees in the table.I want the status of only 5 specific employees from the table

Comment: @Suma Please check the updated answer, as I have taken your feedback into account.

Comment: Thank you once again.But this will retrieve the count of Completed Status.If this count doesn't retrieve count as 5 I have to use static wait which I don't want to use , because you never know how much time Employee ID will take time to move from Waiting status to Completed Status(This transformation from Waiting to Complete Status is automatic.)

Comment: If you really want to wait for a certain query outcome, then you will need to write some sort of poller or scheduled task.  My answer at least resolves your SQL problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ValidateStatusQuery() throws Exception {
int counter = 0;
List<Integer> EmplyeeIDList= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(123,345,456,567))
Class.forName(dbdriver);    
con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL2,DB_UserName,DB_Password);
log.info("Data base connection is established");
int i=0;
while(i++<EmplyeeIDList.size()) {
    if(counter==5)
        break;
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from tb_Employee where EmployeeID=?");                    
    stmt.setInt(1,EmplyeeIDList.get(i));            
    rs3= stmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs3.next()) {             
        getCurrentStatus= rs3.getString("CurrentStatus");
        if(getCurrentStatusID.equals("1")) {
            log.info(+EmplyeeIDList.get(i) + " is in Completed Status");
            counter++;//Incrementing counter variable whenever employee id is in  
            Completed Queue. 
            System.out.println("Count is"+counter);
        } else if(getCurrentStatusID.equals("7")) {
            log.info(+EmplyeeIDList.get(i) + " is in Waiting Status");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            --i;//Decreasing the value by 1
        } else if(getCurrentStatusID.equals("3")) {
            log.info(+EmplyeeIDList.get(i) + " is in Error Status");
        }
    }   //End of While rs loop      
}
```

}